# Trouble with javascript timer and php variables

Tags: javascript, php

I have been at this for quite a while now but can't seem to crack why this javascript timer, using PHP variables will not actually count down...

Here is my code

```
<script>
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['mydropdown'] == 1){
        $var = ($_SESSION['timer'] + 0.1 * 60) -  time();
        }
        else {
             $var = ($_SESSION['timer'] + 1440 * 60) -  time();
        }
        ?>

        setInterval(function() { 
            var difference = Math.floor('<?php echo $var ;?>');
            var seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
            difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

            var minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
            difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

            var hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
            difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

            var days = difference;
            $("#Timer").text(seconds + " Seconds"+ minutes + "m" + hours + "h" + days + "d" );
            }, 1000);

    </script>

    You will be logged out in : <span id="Timer"></span>
```

Basically the first timer if the `dropdown` is 1 should be 6 seconds, which it is, however it is stationary on 6 seconds and doesn't count down at all... I changed this directly from another function that is counting down properly, but I can't seem to find out where I have gone wrong with this one and why won't it actually count down. Basically I want it to go from 6 to 5 to 4 and so on to 0, if it were 6 seconds.

I have jquery/jscript installed as my other timer is working, that does not contain php variables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code as it is received by the browser (view source code for the URL).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I'm not following I rightclicked the page and hit view source code, and it's exactly the same as what is posted there above

Comment: That explains it then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this `var difference = Math.floor(<?php echo $var; ?>);` statement outside the anonymous function called by `setInterval`. And you don't need `'` single quote

You code should be like this:

```
var difference = Math.floor('<?php echo $var ;?>');

setInterval(function() { 
    var d = difference;                       // This line is added
    var seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

    var days = difference;
    difference = d - 1;                       // This line is added
    $("#Timer").text(seconds + " Seconds"+ minutes + "m" + hours + "h" + days + "d" );
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Progress, however it jumps from 6 straight to 0

Comment: @Jim, I added 2 line the the code, please check again

Comment: @Jim, I think you might want to stop the timer when count down becomes zero. Or you might want to redirect to login page. Hope you can do it! Otherwise ask new question.

Comment: is there a way to auto redirect, i do have a "header(Location : login.php)" however I have to refresh this to take me back, it doesn't auto redirect if you know what I mean, when the timer hits 0 it calls this, however i need to refresh before the page gets loaded

Comment: @Jim, so, post a new question.